# unassigned variable error while using ternary operator

Tags: java, string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);       
    String s = in.nextLine();         
    String l,b;         
    for(int i=0;i<(s.length()-2);i++) {
    if(i==0) {
        l=s.substring(i,i+3);     
        s.substring(i,i+3).compareTo(s.substring(i+1,i+4))>0
          ? l=s.substring(i,i+3)
          : l=s.substring(i+1,i+4); // assigned values
        s.substring(i,i+3).compareTo(s.substring(i+1,i+4))<0
          ? b=s.substring(i,i+3)
          : b=s.substring(i+1,i+4);
    }
```

why does it show variable i and b not assigned?

Comment: Downvoting because of totally horrible code style.  Seriously, if you want people to read your code you need to do better than this.  IMO, this is bordering on disrespectful!

Comment: fixed by Niall Cosgrove with a little contribution by me

Comment: Hint: even when this code is properly formatted, it is still absolutely horrible. You really want to study "Cleancode" by Robert Martin for example to understand how much even this little bit of code could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

First, you **cannot** *nest* ternary assignments to `l` and `b` like you appear to be trying to do (and you also seem to ***try*** and assign the same values to both). You **could** do so before the loop like

```
b = l = s.substring(0, 3).compareTo(s.substring(1, 4)) > 0 ? 
        s.substring(0, 3) : s.substring(1, 4);
```

then make your initial loop condition `1` like

```
for (int i = 1; i < (s.length()-2); i++) {
    // ...
}
```

and there is no need to test for `0` if the loop starts at `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Ternary expressions' purpose is to return values.  Specifically, the expression has a value that is chosen from two possible values, depending on a condition.  That value can then be used anywhere any other expression can be used, e.g.

```
x = (isSomeTestTrue()) ? 2 : 5;
System.out.println((isSomeOtherTestTrue()) ? "this" : "that");
```

You're trying to use it in place of an `if` statement.  That is, you're putting statements that do work in the `?` and `:` parts, and ignoring the value of the expression:

```
s.substring(i,i+3).compareTo(s.substring(i+1,i+4)) > 0
    ? l = s.substring(i,i+3)
    : l = s.substring(i+1,i+4);
```

Don't do that.  This is not what a ternary expression is for.  And it won't always work (I think that the using a ternary expression like this might not be good enough to satisfy the rules for "definite assignment" of `l`, although the rules are complicated and I'm still trying to figure them out).  Note: This might be an acceptable idiom in some languages, such as Perl or JavaScript.  But I don't think you should do this in Java or C#.

If you have two statements, and you want to execute one if the condition is true, and another if it's false, use `if`.

```
if (s.substring(i,i+3).compareTo(s.substring(i+1,i+4)) > 0) {
    l = s.substring(i, i+3);
} else {
    l = s.substring(i+1, i+4);
}
```

Or, in this case, you could use a ternary operator and assign the result into `l`:

```
l = (s.substring(i, i+3).compareTo(s.substring(i+1, i+4)) > 0)
        ? s.substring(i, i+3)
        : s.substring(i+1, i+4);
```